CSS grid with flexible height, how do i fit container around content?
I have this jsfiddle:
The two grids overlapp,


.flexgrid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);
  column-gap: 1vw;
  row-gap: 1vh;
  container-type: size;
  block-size: min-content;
  min-height: 50px; }
  ul.flexgrid {
    list-style-type: none; }
  .flexgrid > * {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100cqw; }

.marker-red {
  border: 1px solid #f00; }

.marker-green {
  border: 1px solid #0f0; }

.horz50 {
  width: 50%; }
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <p>Paragraph-Test.</p>
  <div class="marker-red horz50">
    <ul class="flexgrid">
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 1</li>
      <li>testtext 2</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 3</li>
      <li>testtext 4</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 5</li>
      <li>testtext 6</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="marker-red">
    <ul class="flexgrid">
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 1</li>
      <li>testtext 2</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 3</li>
      <li>testtext 4</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 5</li>
      <li>testtext 6</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>



because they dont get their hight from their children, so box-size is not applied. How can I do this?

use inline-size instead of size

container-type values (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container-type):
size
Establishes a query container for container size queries in both the inline and block dimensions. Applies layout containment, style containment, and size containment to the container.
Size containment is applied to the element in both the inline and block directions. The size of the element can be computed in isolation, ignoring the child elements.
inline-size
Establishes a query container for dimensional queries on the inline axis of the container. Applies layout, style, and inline-size containment to the element.
Inline size containment is applied to the element. The inline size of the element can be computed in isolation, ignoring the child elements.
Fiddle
In our case inline-size is a better fit.


.flexgrid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);
  column-gap: 1vw;
  row-gap: 1vh;
  container-type: inline-size;
  block-size: min-content;
  min-height: 50px; }
  ul.flexgrid {
    list-style-type: none; }
  .flexgrid > * {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100cqw; }

.marker-red {
  border: 1px solid #f00; }

.marker-green {
  border: 1px solid #0f0; }

.horz50 {
  width: 50%; }
<h1>Headline</h1>
  <p>Paragraph-Test.</p>
  <div class="marker-red horz50">
    <ul class="flexgrid">
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 1</li>
      <li>testtext 2</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 3</li>
      <li>testtext 4</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 5</li>
      <li>testtext 6</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="marker-red">
    <ul class="flexgrid">
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 1</li>
      <li>testtext 2</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 3</li>
      <li>testtext 4</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 5</li>
      <li>testtext 6</li>
      <li class="marker-green">testtext 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>



